# C# String and Digits Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

How can I allow the users that can only type 2words that only accepts M and C word and 5 digits number (0-9) ? 
For example MC04326 
Here is my code so far

```
else if (!(new Regex(@"^(MC)(([][0-9])$")).IsMatch(txtStudentIDReg.Text))
{ 

}
```

Comment: The regex pattern you want is `^MC[0-9]{5}$`.  You might want to review a good regex tutorial to learn more about it.

Comment: If MC are fixed then why don't you use a simple NumericUpDown control or a MaskEdit one to leave only the input for the numeric part?

Comment: `else if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtStudentIDReg.Text, @"^MC[0-9]{5}$")) { ... }`

Comment: Yes it works now. But, how can I disable all letters except M and C when typing? and after MC only digits number can be typed

Comment: Is "CMxxxxx" a valid input or do you accept only "MCxxxxx"?

Comment: accept only "MCxxxxx" , but nevermind my problem solved now 
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for regex with such simple validation:

```
// str is inputted string
var isValid = 
  str.StartsWith("MC") && // starts with MC
  str.Substring(2).All(ch => char.IsDigit(ch)) && // after second character, all are digits
  str.Length == 7; // is of length 7
```

Comment: Please, add check for `str.Length == 7` otherwise `"MC123456789"` will be valid